# OpenCV and the latest PS3 Eye driver

Tags: c++, opencv

My question is if anyone has a way on how to use the PS3 eye with openCV.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just install appropriate driver (for example, [here's](http://nuigroup.com/forums/viewthread/2921/) Windows version). After that Ps3eye will behave as an ordinary web cam.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CL-EYE driver

http://codelaboratories.com/products/eye/driver/

Free Driver License - Single camera support for personal non-commercial use. For commercial applications or more than 1 camera, you have to pay a license, but it's not expensive

Comment: Both options there require Paypal payment from now on (around 2.5$ for a driver that should be free - and has alternatives). I would not recommend it as they changed their policy in a bad way.